# Why a can't connect my tables in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, innodb

shippings table structure
[image: shippings table structure]
I want to connect in to another table like this(I got "1215 error"):

```
CREATE TABLE goods_and_shippings (
good_id INT NOT NULL,
s_date DATE NOT NULL,
shipping_id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (good_id),
FOREIGN KEY (s_date) REFERENCES shippings(s_date)
```

)

Connected columns have same data types as you can see (both DATE and NOT NULL) and all tables use InnoDB engine. But I have this snippet and it works:

```
CREATE TABLE goods_and_shippings (
good_id INT NOT NULL,
s_date DATE NOT NULL,
shipping_id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (good_id),
FOREIGN KEY (shipping_id) REFERENCES shippings(shipping_id)
```

)

All tables are empty for now. Here is query for creating shippings:

```
CREATE TABLE shippings (
shipping_id INT NOT NULL,
s_date DATE NOT NULL,
driver_id INT NOT NULL,
start_place VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
end_place VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
car_id INT NOT NULL,
price DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (shipping_id, s_date)
```

)

Here alters I've used after:

```
ALTER TABLE shippings ADD CONSTRAINT fk_car_id FOREIGN KEY (car_id) REFERENCES cars(car_id);
ALTER TABLE shippings ADD CONSTRAINT fk_driver_id FOREIGN KEY (driver_id) REFERENCES drivers(driver_id);
```

What's wrong in my queries? How to fix this and connect goods_and_shippings.s_date and shippings.s_date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, foreign key references are to unique or primary keys.  However, this condition is relaxed for INNODB, as explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of
>   columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index
>   where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order.

So, you can have a foreign reference to `shipping_id` because it is the first key in the primary key, but not to date.  However, I would advise you to set up your foreign key relationships to complete primary keys.  And, I usually have an auto-incrementing primary key in all tables, to facilitate such relationships.

Comment: can you tell what exactly I need to do?

Comment: should I reorginize table's structure?

Comment: I've understand. The solution is: 
    FOREIGN KEY (shipping_id, s_date) REFERENCES shippings(shipping_id, s_date)

Comment: @user3528865 . . . That would be the correct foreign key relationship.